# Typescript: Check if a parameter is of a type

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I've created these constructor implementations:

```
constructor(position: FlagPosition, flag: string);
constructor(position: FlagPosition, flag: Expression<any> | string) {
    this.position = position;
    //TODO: Check falg type:
    //if flag is an string
    //    this(position, ExpressionUtils.template(Object.class, flag));
    //else
    //    this.flag = flag;
}
```

I don't know how to check if `flag` parameter is an string or is an `Expression<any>`.

Any ideas?

Comment: `if (typeof flag === "string") { /* do stuff */ }`?

Comment: And in order to check is `flag` is of type `Expression<any>`?

Comment: Either put it in the else clause (and trust that only either strings or expressions are given to your constructor), or if `Expression` is a class, you can do `flag instanceof Expression`. I'm not sure what `Expression` exactly is though.

Comment: `Expression` is an interface...

Comment: in that case it would depend on what its members are / what implements it. Can you post the interface definition?

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
if (typeof flag === "string") {
//
} else if (name instanceof test) {
//
}
```

`

Comment: Would you mind editing your answer in order to check is flag is of type Expression<any>?

Comment: You can't check the type against an interface at runtime. The transpiled javascript doesn't know anything about your Typescript interface definition.

Answer (score 1):

You are mistaken between what happens when TS transpiles to JS and what happens at runtime.

```
flag: Expression<any> | string
```

There, TS will test if you correctly pass a string or a 'Expression' when you call the function. It verifies that during translation to JS ....

While

```
//TODO: Check falg type:
//if flag is an string
//    this(position, ExpressionUtils.template(Object.class, flag));
//else
//    this.flag = flag;
```

is code that will have effect at runtime. At runtime 'Expression'(which is an interface) won't exist anymore (JS doesn't know what an Interface is).

So you test the type of your parameter, but in the body of your constructor you should consider it a simple Object with the properties your interface has.